# Multiple functions with one "function"

Tags: javascript

How can I get by using one function with function names and executions?

```
function
  RunA() {
    alert("I run function A!");
  }
  RunB() {
    alert("I run function B!");
  }
```

If this was explained elsewhere, my apologies.

**Edit:** Trying to create a name for each function without using function every time

Comment: what do you want to do with it?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: The syntax you have used does not work (as you likely tested and found yourself), but depending on what you are trying to accomplish, it's likely to be possible. Please edit your question with details about _why_ you want to do this. Regardless of how you might write it, what is your end desire?

Comment: More info... the point of a function is to have one job. don't overcomplicate things by giving one method multiple internal functions

Comment: I know i could use IF ELSE for this but as having lots of function names, is this format okay?

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. Run two functions on page load? Define two different functions with less typing? Add a helper function as part of a main function? Something else?

Comment: (part of me wishes i need to do it first then ask)

Comment: Less typing for sure @Phorogz

Comment: My thought on it was Function was treated as like Doctype in html and charset in CSS.  But i can be wrong

Comment: @GarethCompton it wouldn't be wise to compare anything in the javascript world to HTML, HTML at the end of the day is simply a document with 'markup' that defines a structure.

Comment: (Pardon my ignorance, simply learning as i go along) I thought function is the markup for java because of the syntax of Function FunctionName() {

Comment: (oops) 

    function
        functionName() {
            // function does something
        }

Comment: @GarethCompton first javascript is NOT java, while javascript has java in it, in no way is it the same language.  Be careful not to interchange the two.  In a way you are correct about a function, however a function is a block of code to perform a task.  An HTML element is not performing a task, it's just a tag that the browser interprets and displays according to it's guidelines.

Comment: oops pardon my java vs javascript error, i achnoledge that.  and that makes sense

Comment: @GarethCompton Perhaps you should read about JavaScript syntax. For example, you might find this easier (or you might find it super confusing): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I got it @Phorgz, i have been playing with my advance calculator with the normal typing of JavaScript, just wasn't sure I can get away with it.  If i can, i will write my answer (lack of testing it on myself)

Comment: But again, thanks for the lecture, didnt understand the advance portion but I have a general syntax of it (the normal JavaScript way)

Comment: Is that why I am getting "undefined" errors? (just now tested it and obviously didnt work)  Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: While it might seem like a good idea to save as much typing as possible, generally even if this was syntactically valid it is not a good idea to overcomplicate well defined customs in the name of fancy looking code.

Just use

```
function RunA(){
    alert("I run function A!");
};

function RunB(){
    alert("I run function B!");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No but you could do

```
function RunA(){
    alert("I run function A!");
};

function RunB(){
    alert("I run function B!");
};

function RunAB(){
    RunA();
    RunB();
};
```